# MYSQL Select multiple entries

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Table: chats [ ChatID |   Name   ]
             [    1   | TestChat ]

Table: chat_members [ ChatID | CharacterID ]
                    [    1   |     1755    ]
                    [    1   |       6     ]
```

---

```
SELECT * FROM chats INNER JOIN chat_members ON (chats.ChatID = chat_members.ChatID) WHERE chat_members.CharacterID = 1755
```

> [{"ChatID":1,"Name":"TestChat","ChatID1":1,"CharacterID":1755}]

How is it possible to get the following callback?

> [{"ChatID":1,"Name":"TestChat","ChatID1":1,"CharacterID":1755,"ChatID2":1,"CharacterID1":6}]

I want to get from the CharacterID the chat in table chats and all entrys in chats_members... any ideas?

Comment: Use 2 copies of `chat_members` table - first for chat defining, second for users search.

Comment: *How is it possible to get the following callback?* This callback makes no sense DIRECTLY - you mix two different entities. And the shown output formally produces dynamic output structure.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT c1.*, m2.*
-- use 1st copy of members list
FROM chat_members m1
-- find the chat where the member in interest is participated
JOIN chats c1 ON m1.ChatID = c1.ChatID AND m1.CharacterID = 1755
-- use 2nd copy of members list, find all memebers participated in the chat found
JOIN chat_members m2 ON m2.ChatID = c1.ChatID
```

or (this form is more clear for half the people, and nothing differs except the query text)

```sql
SELECT c1.*, m2.*
FROM chats c1
-- use 1st copy of members list
-- and find the chat where the member in interest is participated
JOIN chat_members m1 ON m1.ChatID = c1.ChatID AND m1.CharacterID = 1755
-- use 2nd copy of members list, find all memebers participated in the chat found
JOIN chat_members m2 ON m2.ChatID = c1.ChatID
```

Comment: both querys returns: {"ChatID":1,"Name":"TestChat","LastPost":0,"ChatID1":1,"CharacterID":6}